# How do I show the "to" header contents near the subject?

Tags: outlook, office365

When I open a mail, either by single or double clicking it (the later resulting in the mail being opened in a dialog), I want to be able to read the "To" header contents in the field where I can see the subject and the sender (and also the senders avatar if any).

How do I do that?

Comment: Web or COM add-in?

Comment: I am using the email client.

Comment: Which can run either a web add-in or COM add-in. So which are you building or want to build? They are completely different APIs

Comment: This is not a programming question per se.

Comment: Can you clarify? Your question first asks "How do I show" - but that implies customization.  The header is not customizable (I'm excluding legacy custom Outlook forms because you don't want to use that, trust me).

Comment: If the header is not customizable, then the answer is that it is impossible.